Etsy .../listings/active API call returns the wrong amount of active listings
My store has 299 active listings but when I try to get the active listings through the Etsy API, the API only returns 175 active listings. Why is there such a discrepancy?
Here is a screenshot from my store:

Here is my API code:
const url = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/{shopId}/listings/active';
     
const response = await axios.get(url, 
      {
          headers: 
          {
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${_accessToken}`,
              'x-api-key': clientID,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          params: {
              limit: 50,
              offset: 0,
              sort_order: "asc",
              sort_on: "created"
          }
      });

      console.log(response.data.count); // This returns 175 but I have 299 active 
                                           listings in my store
    }


I feel like there are some missing details. I would honestly check your actual store active listings vs. what's the API supposed to return, maybe you missed something somewhere.

I am not sure what I could be missing. The api call is supposed to return the number of active listings. It should match the number shown on the UI, no?
